# WPF, Canvas, FormattedText.BuildGeometry - why is nothing displayed?

Tags: wpf, path, canvas, geometry

I have a need to display text mixed with geometries - and so far I have the geometries displayed nicely (removed from example below), but the text doesn't show up at all.

I've found the example for formatted text below and think I should be able to take the buildGeometry and enclose it in a path to be shown in a canvas.

Can anybody help me see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for any responses,

Anders, Denmark

```
        var canvas = new Canvas();
        var formattedText = new FormattedText(
            "Hello world",
            CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"),
            FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
            new Typeface("Verdana"),
            32,
            Brushes.Black);
        var buildGeometry = formattedText.BuildGeometry(new Point(500, 500));
        var path = new System.Windows.Shapes.Path();
        path.Data = buildGeometry;
        canvas.Children.Add(path);

        Content = canvas;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ay caramba,

A Path needs a Stroke defined in order to show anything(!).

Apologies to all spending time on my question....

```
        var path = new System.Windows.Shapes.Path
        {
            Stroke = Brushes.Black,
            StrokeThickness = 1
        };
```